# calculating length of several files in pandas using for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have five data frames `(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)`, and I am going to calculate their lengths using the following code:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_2.xlsx")
df3 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_3.xlsx")
df4 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_4.xlsx")
df5 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_5.xlsx")

for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    print(len(dfi.index))
```

But it throws the following error:

```
"name 'dfi' is not defined"
```

I also tried this:

```
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    print(len(df[i].index))
```

But that did not work.

This code works:

```
print(len(df1.index))
```

But I have to change name of the file each time.

What is problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you post more than just your loop? It isn't clear what how you're doing what you're doing. Try `df[i]`.

Comment: Could you add a [mcve] to the question? It's hard to know what you try to do. If the dataframes are inside a list you could use `for dfi in name_of_your_df_list:`.

Comment: This is not working because you don't have variable named `dfi`. You probably want to put you dataframes into a list and iterate over them.

Comment: @MSeifert, is it clear now ?

Comment: @COLDSPEED, is it clear now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no dynamic variable names in Python - so `dfi` refers to a variable explicitly called `dfi`. It doesn't change to `df1` just because `i` is `1` (or something else).

In your case you could simply iterate over a sequence of the dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_2.xlsx")
df3 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_3.xlsx")
df4 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_4.xlsx")
df5 = pd.read_excel("/Users/us/Desktop/cymbalta_rated_5.xlsx")

for dfi in (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5):   # explicitly defines the variable "dfi"!
    print(len(dfi.index))
```